# Change Workbench state from Draft to Published programatically

Tags: workbench

I would like to do a bulk operation and change nodes from a state of Draft to Published. I created a new revision from a previous change, but all revisions default to Draft. Now I would like to basically just publish the new revision. (I am using the Workbench module.)

I have tried doing things like the below, but none of them seem to work:

```
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->published = "1";
```

or

```
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->from_state = "draft";
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->state = "published";
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->published = "1";

$node->workbench_moderation['published']->from_state = "draft";
$node->workbench_moderation['published']->state = "published";
$node->workbench_moderation['published']->published = "1";

$node->workbench_moderation['my_revision']->from_state = "draft";
$node->workbench_moderation['my_revision']->state = "published";
$node->workbench_moderation['my_revision']->published = "1";
$node->workbench_moderation['my_revision']->current = TRUE;
```

or

```
workbench_moderation_moderate($node, 'published');
```

I've tried saving using the below rather than `node_save` as well, thinking maybe the `node_save` triggered a new draft.

```
workbench_moderation_node_update($node);
```

**I just want to simply load the node, publish the draft, then save it again.**

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two solutions which I have found will work:

**The First:**

```
$nid = 1234;
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->body['und'][0]['value'] = 'new body';
$node->revision = 1;
$node->log = 'State Changed to published';
node_save($node);
workbench_moderation_moderate($node, 'published');
```

*NOTE:* I intentionally put `workbench_moderation_moderate()` after `node_save()` because in my case `node_save()` will trigger a new draft.  After the draft is created, I publish that draft.

**The second:**

```
$nid = 1234;
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->body['und'][0]['value'] = 'new body';
$node->workbench_moderation_state_new = workbench_moderation_state_published();
$node->revision = 1;
$node->log = 'State Changed to published';
node_save($node);
```

I am going with the first solution over the second solution because of the status messages. The first shows the two messages under the current revision:

```
From Draft --> Published on...
From Published --> Draft on...
```

whereas the second solution only shows one message which doesn't really make much sense:

```
From Published --> Published on...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Keven

The second solution is the correct one! You just have to load the most recent revision with node_load. node_save() triggers the workbench_moderation_moderate() function so you don't have to do it after node_save() manually!

```
$query = db_select('workbench_moderation_node_history', 'wmnh');
$query->addField('wmnh', 'vid');
$query->condition('wmnh.nid', $nid);
$query->condition('wmnh.current', 1);
$current = $query->execute()->fetchField();

// or you can get the latest revision id by loading the node without revision id:
$node = node_load($nid);
// Altough you can get node revision id from node object itself i prefer using the workbench_moderation property.
// $current = $node->vid;
$current = $node->workbench_moderation['current']->vid;

$node = node_load($nid, $current);
$node->workbench_moderation_state_new = workbench_moderation_state_published();
$node->revision = 1;
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, in Workbench Moderation 7.x-2.x-dev, this worked to unpublish a node:

```
$node = node_load(218821);
$node->status = NODE_NOT_PUBLISHED;
$node->event = 'to_unpublished';
node_save($node);
```